# Downloading file do not display total file size and time (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Please somebody tell me how to show the Total file size and download time while sending bytes from server to the browser. 
I am trying to send large bytes(1 Gb) bytes by bytes to the client.Here is the code i tried:

```
long dataToRead;
int length;
byte[] buffer = new Byte[100000];
FileStream iStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

dataToRead = iStream.Length;
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file);
while (dataToRead > 0)
{
    // Verify that the client is connected.
    if (Response.IsClientConnected)
    {
        // Read the data in buffer.
        length = iStream.Read(buffer, 0, 10000);

        // Write the data to the current output stream.
        await Response.OutputStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, length);

        // Flush the data to the HTML output.
       Response.Flush();

        buffer = new Byte[100000];
        dataToRead = dataToRead - length;
    }
    else
    {
        dataToRead = -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Notice that in your code example, even on the server side you don't know how large the file is.  How would you expect to tell the client and report progress against the total size?

Comment: What a waste of manual coding. Why aren't you just using `return FileStream(iStream)`?

Comment: Thanks @Kyle Burns for your reply, I just want that code ,could you please help me in writing such code

Comment: return FileStream(iStream) does not return file of size 1 GB @ Camilo Terevinto.

Comment: I wonder from where you gathered that information... However, you just need to add a Header with the file size.

Comment: Thanks @Camilo Terevinto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding a `Content-Length` header to let the browser know what the size is:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", dataToRead.ToString());
// Remainder of your code
```